# Screen not covering entirety of monitor area on new flat screen

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, resolution

I have purchased a new 27" monitor.  My previous monitor was 22".  I have setup the monitor and it is working fine, just that the viewable screen size is not quite as large as the monitor viewing area.

I had a look online and suggestions are to increase the screen resolution.  I am currently on 1920 x 1080 pixels.  Is the fact that I cannot increase the screen resolution because my graphics card is not powerful enough?

My graphics card does not have a hdmi port so I am plugging in via a Displayport to hdmi cable.  The card is an AMD Catalyst FirePro V5900.

Monitor is a Dell SE2719HR - 27".

Comment: What is the monitor?

Comment: Often in a monitor's settings menu there will be an option that places horizontal and vertical arrows on the screen that allow the user to manually widen and increase the height of the video output so that it aligns with the screen's edges.